# Literate Programming in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, literate-programming

What possible solutions are there for using Visual Studio with literate programming? Are there ready plugins or built-in solutions or integrations?

(This is not about general discussions about literate programming or visual studio alternatives)

Comment: I found only https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Rookboom.Elucidate. Option is to use docstrings and to generate docs, which is not LP (DocFX and similar)